# How does the web server choose between unicode and utf-8 for accented characters?

Tags: apache

I have a web server with my ISP which replaces accented characters in URLs with their unicode values: for instance é (eacute) is translated to %e9 (dec 233).

For testing locally I use EasyPHP which translates those characters by their utf-8 equivalence: é is then replaced by the well known sequence %c3%a9 (Ã©)...
Browsers served by EasyPHP don't decode unicode values but they do if running locally (utf-8 and non converted accent also)...

I have been unable to find where this behavior is configured in the server.

This is a problem as some urls are built by my application using the php rawurlencode() which seems to always encode with unicode values on both servers.
Any idea?

Comment: UTF-8 _is_ a Unicode encoding. The first encoding is most-likely ISO-8859-1 or some similar encoding, like Windows-1252.

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple ways to set character encoding.

1. php.ini - `default_charset = "utf-8"`
2. php header - `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');`
3. html meta - `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
4. .htaccess - `AddCharset UTF-8 .html`

For more on the subject check out [UTF-8: The Secret of Character Encoding](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) or [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) and [mbstring runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php)

Comment: already run arouund all these (1 to 4), will concentrate on the mbstring items. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change the default character encoding, you need to [edit your Apache configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server) (httpd.conf):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```